# decodeStream not populating recyclerView with Bitmap image

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-bitmap

I want to populate my recyclerview with small(60x60) album art bitmap, but i cant seem to get it. I've tried everything i knew, please help.

The code i'm using to scale down images:

```
public static int calculateSize(BitmapFactory.Options opt, int reqHeight, int reqWidth){
        int height = opt.outHeight;
        int width = opt.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if(height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth){

            final int halfWidth = width/2;
            final int halfHeight = height /2;

            while((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth){
                inSampleSize *= 2;

            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampleBitmapFromArray(InputStream stream, Rect rect, int reqHeight, int reqWidth){
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, rect, options);

        //Calculate sample size
        options.inSampleSize = calculateSize(options, reqHeight, reqWidth);

        //Decode bitmap with insamplesize set false
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return bit;
    }
```

Then i called the decodeSampleBitmapFromArray function in my onCreate method in order to populate my recyclerview Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...

    adapter = new CustomRecycler(paths);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.ryc);

    lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        metaRetriever.setDataSource(path);
        byte[] b = metaRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();

        if (b != null) {
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
            paths.add(decodeSampleBitmapFromArray(in,new Rect(-1,-1,1,1), 60, 60));

        }else{
            Bitmap altIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.beat);
            paths.add(altIcon);
        }

}
```

My RecyclerAdapter then received the bitmap and display it using ImageView

```
holder.artImage.setImageBitmap(mImage.get(position));
```

After doing all this, the images are still not populating the recyclerview. What i'm i doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: CustomRecycler knows only empty paths ... it wasnt inform that content had changed

Comment: I have that in my project, but i mistakenly left it out when posting this code.

Comment: *the images are still not populating the recyclerview*  is misleading ... it is hard to guess if there is no at least placeholders or just images are not loading ... also I do not see any debug code (like at least some "bitmap is null" message)

Comment: Not all the images are not populating the recyclerview, the code within the 'else' condition code is working perfectly fine.
`else{
            Bitmap altIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.beat);
            paths.add(altIcon);
        }`

Comment: so you have krislarson's answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true`, that's exactly what happens — it just decodes the bounds.  Null is always returned for the bitmap.  The idea is that once you know the bounds, you can set `options.inSampleSize` to an appropriate value and decode the image data again.

Carefully look at the method `decodeSampleBitmapFromResource` from this developer page: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

`BitmapFactory.decodeResource` is called *twice*, first with `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true` to get the dimensions, then with `options.inSampleSize` set to produce a bitmap scaled the way you want.

Your code is doing the right stuff getting a value for `options.inSampleSize`, except that you never call `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` again with this value to retrieve the scaled bitmap.